# How to pair up numbers in tournament given k and a specific condition

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, nested-loops

I was asked during the interview. I didn't take a note, so the problem description may be a bit vague.

number is the rank in tournament.

```
k=1, return (1, 2) 
k=2, return ((1, 4), (2, 3)) 
k=3, return (((1, 8), (4, 5)), ((2, 7), (3, 6)))
k=4, return ((((1, 16), (8, 9)), ((4, 13), (5, 12))), (((2, 15), (7, 10)), (3, 14), (6, 11))))
```

The smallest rank should be paired up with the largest rank always. So for example, `k=3 (((1, 8), (4, 5)), ((2, 7), (3, 6))) -> ((1, 4), (2, 3)) -> (1, 2) -> 1 (winner)`

I think the brute force solution is to create a list of numbers given k and pair up between the largest number and the smallest number by incrementing both right and left index. But once paring is done, I should be able to pair up furthermore. For example, when k=3, I can create a list: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` and create a list of pairs: `[(1, 8), (2, 7), (3, 6), (4, 5)]`. After that, I should be able to pair up again to this: `[((1, 8), (4, 5)), ((2, 7), (3, 6))]`

I can't come up with a nested paring rule after I pair up two numbers in the beginning which can apply to any given k number.

Edit: K is given. With k, you can create a list of numbers from 1 to 2**k. So, if k=3, a list of numbers would be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]. And as I mentioned it above, the number represents a rank. So '1' is a winner after the tournament. And since '1' is the winner (the smallest number), '1' should pair up with '8' (the bottom one and the largest number). And as follows (2, 7), (3, 6), (4, 5). But since it's a tournament, you expect that a winner from each pair will match  each other again. Since the condition is that (1st smallest , 1st largest), (2nd smallest, 2nd largest)..., you should pair up ((1, 8), (4, 5)) and ((2, 7), (3, 6)). ((1, 8), (4, 5)) -> (1, 4), ((2, 7), (3, 6)) -> (2, 3) => ((1, 4), (2, 3)) => (1, 2) => 1 (winner)

The goal of the problem is to pair up numbers (by a nested tuple or list) given k and a certain condition ((1st smallest , 1st largest), (2nd smallest, 2nd largest)...).

I tried the brute force solution, which I couldn't think of how to pair up in nested loops given k. I also thought of using a binary tree and a recursive way, which I should know how to pair up given k and the certain condition, and that's where I can't move forward.

Comment: You just asked the same question a few minutes ago (which you deleted), which quickly collected downvotes and closes.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: wait how does k=3 work?

Comment: You are going to have to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

wow hopefully the interviewers did a much better job of explaining the problem statement

maybe this is what you want

```
def get_pairs(L):
    L = sorted(L)
    middle = len(L)//2
    result=list(zip(L[:middle],L[:middle-1:-1]))
    if len(result) > 2:
        return get_pairs(result)
    return result

print get_pairs(range(1,5)) #k=2 ???    
print get_pairs(range(1,9)) #k=3 ???
print get_pairs(range(1,17) #k=4 ???
```

aha I think I figured it(wtf k is and how it relates) out ..

```
def get_pairs_for_rank(k):
    return get_pairs(range(1,2**k+1))
```

Comment: This looks great. I didn't think about using zip. Thank you so much @Joran Beasley. One thing is that you don't need to sort in get_pairs function since the order keeps the same. The result is the same regardless of sorting.

Comment: only if L is already sorted ... if it wasnt it would not work ... I wrote get_pairs before I understood what k was so I didnt know how it would get the lists